# SQL server 2005 - compact edition and express edition

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2005, sql-server-express

I have a database program developed in Visual Studios 2005. It uses SQL Express in creating and connecting to the database. I have created a deployment package with SQL Express. Can this be installed on a PC that has SQL 2005 Compact Edition installed?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Express and SQL Compact are two different versions. You will need to install SQL Express on the PC as well.